# UI Automation can not find button in pane

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

Hoping for anyone who has gone through similar situation..

I am digging a pane returned onto my WebBroswer WPF from a web server.

this pane, which is topped on my WebBrowser has 14 components including everything I see (such as email: textbox, password: passwordbox, hyperlinks.. etc), except the two buttons in bottom right (ok and cancel buttons).

I suspected may be these two buttons are not on the same pane as other controls since I do not see them in the Collection. I have been trying different command lines to get handles of these two buttons, not successful. The method call I used to get other controls except the buttons:

```
AutomationElementCollection Child4 =
     Child3.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, System.Windows.Automation.Condition.TrueCondition);
```

Child3 is localizedControlType: "Pane", Frameworkid: "Win32".  In Child4, I can see all other controls except the two buttons.  I tried differnt commands on Child3 such as:

```
AutomationElementCollection btns =
      Child3.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsEnabledProperty, true));

AutomationElementCollection btns =
      Child3.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.iskeyboardfocusable, true));

AutomationElementCollection btns =
      Child3.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsControlElementProperty, true));
```

I could not find the two buttons.  It would be great if someone can tell me why I can't find the buttons and teach me how to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have used UI Spy from the beginning..

The pane returned from web server had texts, and the buttons were inside the controltype: text..